# Generic Search And Generic Sort Asp.net Core Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have three models: Animal, Dog and Cat.

```cs
public class Animal
{
        
}
```

```cs
public class Dog : Animal
{
        
}
```

```cs
public class Cat: Animal
{
        
}
```

There are two controllers (`DogController` and `CatController`).
In each controller, there is an `Search` action.
These actions return the search result according to the parameters.

```cs
public class DogController : Controller
{
    public DogController()
    {
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

    }

    [Httpost]
    public async Task<IList<MainBaseEntityViewModel>> Search(int pageNumber, int pageSize, Object objCreteriaSearch, Object CreteriaOrderBy)
    {
        ...
        // Search List of Dogs according to the criteria in the parameter objCreteriaSearch and ordered according to the parameter objCreteriaOrderBy

        List<DogViewModel> dogs = new List<DogViewModel>();
        dogs = (from item in _context.Dog
                select new DogViewModel
                {
                    Dog_ID = data.Dog_ID,
                    Dog_Name = data.Dog_Name
                }).ToList();

        return dogs.Cast<Animal>().ToList();
    }
}
```

objCreteriaSearch is an object that contains the search criteria and CreteriaOrderBy is an object that contains the Sort criteria

```
public objCreteriaSearch
{
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
    public string dogId { get; set; }
    public string dogName { get; set; }
}

public objCreteriaOrderBy
{
   public string sortColumn{ get; set; }
   public bool? descOrder { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a dynamic and generic search according to the `objCreteriaSearch` and `objCreteriaOrderBy` parameters,
if the search parameters in the object objCreteriaSearch are defined then they should be added to the query and if the sort parameters are defined, they also should be added to the query. So the query should be dynamic.

Comment: What's your mean about `dynamic and generic search` here? Please describe it in detail.

Comment: if the search parameters in the object objCreteriaSearch are defined then they should be added to the query and if the sort parameters are defined, they also should be added to the query. So the query should be dynamic

Comment: You can judge the current status of these two parameters through if, and then write different linq statements according to different situations.